# what is wrong in int itemCode1. the itemCode1 cannot be repeated in the conditional statement from itemCode

Tags: java, for-loop

The issue of this code is in the **itemCode1.** my expectation to my code is the itemCode1 can be repeated because the code was ask the user to put the number if the item code will do it again or not. the issue here was the itemCode1 cannot repeat in the item code tag. how o repeat this statement?

```
for (itemCode = 1) {

    int itemCode1 = 0;
    double height = 0;
    double weight = 0;

    String[] titleBMI = {"\n", newTab, "Compute BMI", newTab};

        for (int i = 0; i < titleBMI.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(titleBMI[i]);

        }

    System.out.print("Enter Height (in meters): ");
    height = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter Weight (in kilograms): ");
    weight = input.nextDouble();

    double BMI = weight / (height * height);
    double BMIRounded = Math.round(BMI * 10D)/10D;

    String BMIcategory = "";

    
    String[] infoBMI = {newTab, "Your BMI is " + BMIRounded, "Category " + BMIcategory, newTab};

        for (int i = 0; i < infoBMI.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(infoBMI[i]);

        }

    String[] menu1 = {"[1] Compute BMI again?", "[2] Back", newTab};

        for (int i = 0; i < menu1.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(menu1[i]);

        }

        System.out.print("Enter item code number: ");
        itemCode1 = input.nextInt();

        if (itemCode1 == 1) {
            return itemCode = 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your outer `for` loop is wrong. Use a `while` loop instead: `int itemCode = 1; while (itemCode == 1) {`